# Improper duplicate closure of another prefixes question

Tags: support, specific-question

[Is there a word category for those kind of words?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/569618/is-there-a-word-category-for-those-kind-of-words-and-if-yes-where-can-i-find-a-c)

This question has been redirected to a question about a-adjectives, but the question includes other parts of speech. This has been hastily dismissed as something it is not. Can we get the question reopened?

Comment: The question is reopened. I edited to remove the too broad and off-topic request for lists and resources.

Comment: Alas it has been closed again as a dupe of a similar Q.

Comment: Since it was closed by "Community", it would indicate that the OP felt the duplicate satisfied his question.

Comment: Someone should point out half the examples are not adjectives.

Comment: @GArthurBrown Please see Andrew's comment.

Comment: @Cascabel It is my understanding that the answers we provide are supposed to have general applicability past what satisfies one particular user. If a guy comes and gives examples of verbs and adverbs, and someone links to an article about adjectives, that probably indicates the asker doesn't understand parts of speech.

Comment: @Cascabel Okay, I guess not.